# Switching mouse buttons at mousePressEvent() of QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: qt, button, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem

Is there any easy/elegant way of switching the left and right buttons of mouse in mousePressEvent() of QGraphicsPixmapItem? I have my own class derived from QGraphicsPixmapItem so i can implement my own versions of virtual functions. But I cannot think of any easy way to do it.

The hard ways are:

1. Create my own class derived from QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent that can switch buttons and use at mousePressEvent where it will replace default received event.
2. Copy&paste most of code from original mousePressEvent() to mine changing by the way the buttons.

But these 'solutions' doesnt 'speak' to me and appear not elegant. Maybe one of them is elegamnt but i don't have enough XP to see it. Can someone experienced show me some tips?

Comment: Why do you want to switch the buttons?

Comment: I would like to switch default actions binded to them or in future even change them.